# Convert json into dictionary in python accumulating over data

Tags: python, dictionary

Given a json file data.json and I wants to reduce the json file which I store in a variable data_list to three different dictionary crime, crime1 and crime2 by using three different functions

```
    [{"Region": "South", "State": "ALABAMA", "City": "Athens", "Population": "25603", "Murder": "1", "Rape": "1", "Robbery": "16", "Assault": "0", "Burglary": "90", "Theft": "538", "Vehicle_Theft": "8"}, {"Region": "South", "State": "ALABAMA", "City": "Atmore", "Population": "10021", "Murder": "0", "Rape": "3", "Robbery": "14", "Assault": "76", "Burglary": "86", "Theft": "315", "Vehicle_Theft": "12"}]
```

I load it into a variable

```
    with open('/content/data_crime.json', 'r') as f:
          data_list = json.load(f)
```

I want to reduce data_list into three dictionaries: `murder_by_region`, `violent_by_region`, and
`nonviolent_by_region`.

Create dictionary iterate over `data_list` create dictionary using accumulating pattern
`violent_crime` is `Murder` and `Assault` and `non_violent` is `Theft` and `Vehicle_theft`

I do it by using function for making all three dictionary

```
    function takes three parameters:
         
    Key: region or state
    crime : 'Murder' 
    data_list:the list containing dictionaries for each city
```

Comment: What is your attempt in solving the problem ?

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: @BalajiAmbresh output three different dictionary which shows murder_by_region, violent_by_region, and nonviolent_by_region from the json file

Comment: @Sushanth I make the dictionary for each problem but I not get desired result by making function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```py
from collections import defaultdict
import json

murder_by_region = defaultdict(int)
violent_per_region = defaultdict(int)
nonviolent_per_region = defaultdict(int)

with open('/content/data_crime.json') as f:
    data_list = json.load(f)
    for row in data_list:
        region = row['Region']
        murder_by_region[region] += int(row.get('Murder', 0))
        violent_per_region[region] += int(row.get('Murder', 0)) + int(row.get('Assault', 0))
        nonviolent_per_region[region] += int(row.get('Theft', 0)) + int(row.get('Vehicle_Theft', 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not make it a dictionary of dictionaries where the keys are the city names,

And then do this, it can easily be adjusted to get input like yours.

```
with open('data_crime.json', 'r') as File:
    FileData = json.load(File)
    ExitData = {} # empty dict
    nonViolent = ['Robbery', 'Burglary', 'etc..']
    Violent = ['Assult', 'Rape']
    for i in FileData:
        # i is the key or in this case the city name
        numOfNonViolent = 0
        for j in nonViolent:
            numOfNonViolent += FileData[i][j]
        numOfViolent = 0
        for j in Violent:
            numOfViolent += FileData[i][j]
        
        # will make a new key for ExitData the key is the city name
        ExitData[i] = {
            'Violent Crime' : numOfViolent
            'NonViolent Crime' : numOfNonViolent
            'Murder' : FileData[i]['Murder']
        }
```